# Eclipse autocomplete appears outside of screen

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

It seems like I'm the only one having this issue, as I have not found any similar questions on the internet.

Eclipse autocomplete does work for me. The box pops up with the correct suggestions, however, it doesn't appear at the line of code, but far away, seemingly at random positions, e.g. at the bottom corner of the screen and 90% of it overextends to outside of the screen, so it's basically useless. What could cause this? I have no idea how to even begin tracing this issue.

Reinstalling doesn't work. Even complete reinstall of Ubuntu 20.04, then installing Eclipse latest (2021-09) didn't work. So I'm wondering how isn't anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Please show a screenshot and tell which GTK version do you have and which theme you use in Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't show a screenshot, that's why I described it. Whenever I try to capture a screenshot, the popup box hides; libgtk-3-bin 3.24.18-1ubuntu1; just built-in default dark theme

Comment: Is this a fresh installation without additional plugins? You might try to capture a video and then take a screenshot from the video. Eclipse requires GTK 3.20 or higher. So this seems to be fine.